# Is IP rotation "a thing" for improving security in web servers?

Tags: security, ip, cloudflare

In [this article from Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/products/argo-tunnel/), IP rotation is mentioned as a way to protect web servers. 
How does that work? Is this the same as ordinary load-balancing with failover, or something else?

Comment: Everything I can find about IP Rotation is from the perspective of the client. That is, using a variety of IP addresses in a proxy setup, so the servers you are connecting to (for webscraping or perhaps more nefarious purposes) don't detect and block you. I can't find anything about it as a security measure from the server perspective. As you mentioned, maybe they are using the term as an awkward way to refer to load balancing. Or maybe round-robin DNS. I suggest asking Cloudflare for clarification, as that might shed some light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, IP rotation doesn't work for web servers. Public web sites need to expose *something* to be accessible, likely a load balancer or proxy in front of web servers.

Cloudflare meant to contrast it with their origin hiding HTTP2 tunnel. All access is through their security oriented network.